# javascript pagination large array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination, titanium, appcelerator

i have array has over 10K records i need to paginate it , I've found a cool function but its work only in `foreground` in `background` i got Error `undefined _`

for example :

```
var myArray = bla.GetInfo(); //has over 10K records

var page1 =  getPaginatedItems(myArray, 1 , 500 );

//this function working fine only in foreground 
function getPaginatedItems(items, page , per_page ) {

    var page           = page || 1,
        offset         = (page - 1) * per_page,
        paginatedItems = _.rest(items, offset).slice(0, per_page);

    return { page        : page,
             per_page    : per_page,
             total       : items.length,
             total_pages : Math.ceil(items.length / per_page),
             data        : paginatedItems
           };
}
```

i think the problem from this method `_.rest` any ideas how make this function work in background ? if not dose anyone has similar function do same job ! without underscore methods ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by _foreground_ and _background_.

Comment: @Andy when App is alive ( user is open it and using it ) and App in background ( user has closed it )

Comment: If you are on Android you should use a service. Have quick look here: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/138478/background-service-on-android

Comment: no dear i am IOS base

Answer (score 0):

set a per page record here 4

```
      var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26];
var record_per_page = 4;
var page = 0; //when page > 0 then page = pagi   
var pagi = record_per_page; // when page > 0 then pagi = pagi + record_per_page   

var paginate_array = array.slice(page,pagi);

console.log(paginate_array);
```